# Make `contextualStrings` more likely when using SFSpeechRecognitionRequest

Tags: ios, sfspeechrecognizer, apple-speech

I'm using iOS 10 new Speech API, and I'm setting the `SFSpeechRecognitionRequest`'s `contextualStrings`. However the words have a very low probability - I guess - so they don't get recognized. Is there a way I could make them more likely to be recognized?

Comment: I am also looking for that I have added some words and phrases to contextualStrings but I think SFSpeechRecognitionRequest is still unable to read them., Please help if anyone founds how to use it. In my case, simple vocab is recognized correctly but when some special words or we can say some medical terminology words are speak they are not recognised even from contextualStrings

Comment: I think at least until next WWDC there won't be any news on that. You can try using Nuance though. In my case, customising the vocabulary worked just fine.